# namespace issue with WS-Trust

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ws-trust

When I send a request to WS-Trust endpoint, my request includes WS-Trust namespace `http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512`, but the WS-Trust Endpoint throws an error as

```
 <soap:Fault>
     <soap:Code>
        <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
     </soap:Code>
     <soap:Reason>
        <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Unexpected element {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512}RequestSecurityToken found.   Expected {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/}RequestSecurityToken.</soap:Text>
     </soap:Reason>
  </soap:Fault>
```

It works fine if I use the namespace `http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/`, but how do I change on my WS-Trust endpoint so it accepts the request with `http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512`. I have checked my `wsdl` and it has namespace as `http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing the `targetNamespace` in my generated java resources from WSDL.